# How do I add the result of an .apply as a new column in polars?

Tags: python-polars

I have a wide dataframe, and I'm applying some custom logic to some columns to generate a new column. The code looks as follows:

```
expected = (df
    .select(
        pl.col('^SOME_REGEX_THAT_DOESNT_MATTER*$')
    )
   .apply(get_rmse_expected, return_dtype=pl.Float32)
)
```

This works, and returns a dataframe with a single column with my desired values.

How can I get this as a new column in the original dataframe?

I tried various forms of `.with_column` but none did the trick; and without row identifiers I don't feel at ease doing a concatenation.

Any ideas?

## EDIT: Here is a more detailed example

Consider:

```
import polars as pl 

df = pl.DataFrame({
    "foo": [1, 2],
    "bar": [.1, .2],
})

def mysum(row:tuple[float])->float: 
    '''This code is illustrative - meant to be a row-wise UDF'''
    return sum(row)
```

This code works:

```
df.select(['foo','bar']).apply(mysum)


shape: (2, 1)
┌───────┐
│ apply │
│ ---   │
│ f64   │
╞═══════╡
│ 1.1   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2.2   │
└───────┘
```

And I can even run .rename to get

```
df.select(['foo','bar']).apply(mysum).rename({'apply':'foo+bar'})

shape: (2, 1)
┌─────────┐
│ foo+bar │
│ ---     │
│ f64     │
╞═════════╡
│ 1.1     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2.2     │
└─────────┘
```

But how do I get this as a new column in the original dataframe?

My desired output is

```
shape: (2, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬─────────┐
│ foo ┆ bar ┆ foo+bar │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---     │
│ i64 ┆ f64 ┆ f64     │
╞═════╪═════╪═════════╡
│ 1   ┆ 0.1 ┆ 1.1     │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ 0.2 ┆ 2.2     │
└─────┴─────┴─────────┘
```

## EDIT 2: A more clear example

I appreciate the pl.fold idea, but it solves my illustrative problem, not the general idea of how to add the output of a generic row-wise operation as a new column.

This example may better illustrate that I'm trying to solve for a generic UDF, not one that I plan to express as a polars expression.

```
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "foo": [16, 28, 0 ],
    "bar": [None, 4,17 ],
    "yat": [41, 174,15 ],
    "tar": [None, 4,0 ],
})

def my_apply(row: tuple[float])->str: 
    '''This code is illustrative - meant to be a row-wise UDF'''
    return ' + '.join([f'{x}x{"^"+str(i) if i>0 else ""}' for i,x in enumerate(row) if x!=0 and x is not None])

df.select(['foo','bar', 'yat', 'tar']).apply(my_apply).rename({'apply':'poly'})


shape: (3, 1)
┌────────────────────────────┐
│ poly                       │
│ ---                        │
│ str                        │
╞════════════════════════════╡
│ 16x + 41x^2                │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 28x + 4x^1 + 174x^2 + 4x^3 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 17x^1 + 15x^2              │
└────────────────────────────┘
```

#### My desired output is

```
shape: (3, 5)
┌─────┬──────┬─────┬──────┬────────────────────────────┐
│ foo ┆ bar  ┆ yat ┆ tar  ┆ poly                       │
│ --- ┆ ---  ┆ --- ┆ ---  ┆ ---                        │
│ i64 ┆ i64  ┆ i64 ┆ i64  ┆ str                        │
╞═════╪══════╪═════╪══════╪════════════════════════════╡
│ 16  ┆ null ┆ 41  ┆ null ┆ 16x + 41x^2                │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 28  ┆ 4    ┆ 174 ┆ 4    ┆ 28x + 4x^1 + 174x^2 + 4x^3 │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 0   ┆ 17   ┆ 15  ┆ 0    ┆ 17x^1 + 15x^2              │
└─────┴──────┴─────┴──────┴────────────────────────────┘
```

In pandas you'd do this as:
`df.assign(poly = lambda x: x.apply(my_apply, axis=1))`

## SOLVED:

```
(df.with_columns(
   pl.struct(pl.col(['foo','bar','yat','tar']))
     .apply(lambda x: my_apply(x.values()))
     .alias('poly'))
)
```

Or

```
(df.with_columns(
   pl.struct(pl.col('*'))
     .apply(lambda x: my_apply(x.values()))
     .alias('poly'))
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to apply a function over multiple columns you need to pack them into a `struct` type. This packing is free, but is needed to suffice the expression rules, that every expressions input only consist of a single datatype. E.g. an expression is `Fn(Expr) -> Expr`.

Below shows an example of using an `apply` to compute the horizontal sum and the more idiomatic way to compute a horizontal sum.

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "foo": [1, 2],
    "bar": [.1, .2],
})

def mysum(row: tuple[float])->float: 
    '''This code is illustrative - meant to be a row-wise UDF'''
    return sum(row)


df.with_column(
    # horizontal sum with a custom apply
    pl.struct(["foo", "bar"]).apply(lambda x: mysum((x["foo"], x["bar"]))).alias("foo+bar"),
    # ideomatic way to do a horizontal sum
    pl.sum(["foo", "bar"]).alias("foo+bar")
)
```

### Folds

If you want to do more complicated horizontal aggregations, but want to keep the code fast (as using a python function in `apply` is not), you can use `folds`. Below I show how to compute a horizontal sum with a fold.

```py
df.with_column(
    pl.fold(
        acc=0,
        f=lambda a, b: a + b,
        exprs=pl.all()
    ).alias("foo+bar")
)
```

Comment: Hi, I don't think my question was clear enough. I've added an edit that clarifies my ask.

Comment: Thank you. To clarify, my actual udf is not a sum, just wanted to keep it simple.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think pl.fold allows for f to apply to the whole row at once, it seems to be limited to an accumulation style operation.

Comment: AH! I got it (from your code) `df.with_columns(pl.struct(['foo','bar','yat','tar']).apply(lambda x: my_apply(x.values())).alias('poly'))`